# How to position tooltip and arrow relative to outer container with CSS

Tags: css, tooltip, css-position

I have a document split into three columns. I have images inside A or SPAN in the left and right columns, and text in the middle column. I have classes L and R for the outer columns.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang=en>
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <TITLE>favorite things</TITLE>
        <META name="KEYWORDS" CONTENT="filk">
        <style>
            p        {
                       left:20%;
                       position:relative;
                       right:-20%;
                       margin-left:2em;
                       width:60%;
                     }

            p.drop   {
                       margin-left:2em;
                     }

            p.drop::first-letter  {
                       font-size:2em;
                       margin-left:-2em;
                     }

            a.L,div.L,span.L {
                       display:inline;
                       --width:14%;
                       width:var(--width);
                       position:absolute;
                       left:-20%;
                     }

            a.R,div.R,span.R {
                       display:inline;
                       --width:14%;
                       width:var(--width);
                       position:absolute;
                       right:00%;
                     }

            h1       {
                       text-align:center;
                       font-size:4em;
                     }

            img.V    {
                       display:block;
                       height:auto;
                       margin:10% 10% 10% 10%;
                       max-width:90%;
                       width:100%;
                     }

           /* Tooltip container */
          .tooltip {
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
            border-bottom: 1px dotted black; /* If you want dots under the hoverable text */
          }

          /* Tooltip text */
          .tooltip .tooltiptext {
            visibility: hidden;
            width: 120px;
            background-color: #555;
            color: #fff;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 5px 0;
            border-radius: 6px;

            /* Position the tooltip text */
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 1;
            bottom: 102%;
            left: -25%;
            margin-left: -40%;
            Min-width: 20em;
            max-width: 70em;

            /* Fade in tooltip */
            opacity: 0;
            transition: opacity 0.3s;
          }

          .L .tooltiptext {
            left:  -25%;
            text-align: left;
          }

          .R  .tooltiptext {
            right: 0%;
            text-align: left;
          }

          /* Tooltip arrow */
          .tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            top: 100%;
            left: 50%;
            margin-left: -5px;
            border-width: 5px;
            border-style: solid;
            border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
            width: 1px;
          }

          .L .tooltiptext::after {
            left: calc(--width * (2/3));
          }

          .R .tooltiptext::after {
            left: 30%;
          }

          /* Show the tooltip text when you mouse over the tooltip container */
          .tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
            visibility: visible;
            opacity: 1;
          }

          .verse     {
            font-size: 2em;
            text-align: center;
            width:60%
          }
        </style>
</head>
<BODY LANG="en-US" DIR="LTR">
<H1>My favorite things</H1>

<p>
[Verse]
</p>
<p class="drop verse">
Gardening
<a class=tooltip href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ungoliant">
   spiders
   <span class=tooltiptext>
     Ungoliant, who took the form of a giant spider and, along with Dark Lord Melkor, destroyed the Two Trees of Valinor
   </span>
</a>
<a class=L href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Silmarillion">
<img class=V src="../Images/Silmarillion.png"
             alt="The Silmarillion">
</a>
<br>
<a class="R tooltip" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fellowship_of_the_Ring">
  <img class=V src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/8/8e/The_Fellowship_of_the_Ring_cover.gif"
               alt="The Fellowship of the Ring">
  <span class=tooltiptext>
     Elendil&apos;s sword Narsil, called <q>The Sword that was Broken</q> after
     its damage in a battle against Sauron, and later caried by
     Aragorn (<q>Strider</q>).
  </span>
</a>
And
<a class=tooltip href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle-earth_weapons_and_armour#Narsil">
  swords that are broken
  <span class=tooltiptext>
     Elendil&apos;s sword Narsil, called <q>The Sword that was Broken</q> after
     its damage in a battle against Sauron, and later caried by
     Aragorn (<q>Strider</q>).
  </span>
</a>
<br>
Words in the
<a class=tooltip href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Speech">
  Black Speech
  <span class=tooltiptext>
    The Black Speech of Mordor is a language constructed by Sauron.
  </span>
</a>
<br>
That must not be spoken
<br>
<a class=tooltip href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denethor">
  Unfaithful stewards
  <span class=tooltiptext>
    Denethor, the 26th ruling Steward of Gondor.
  </span>
</a>
<br>
<a class="L tooltip" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Return_of_the_King">
  <img class=V src="../Images/81UzbZbGPUL._SL1500_.jpg"
               alt="The Return of the King">
  <span class=tooltiptext>
    Denethor, the 26th ruling Steward of Gondor.
  </span>
</a>
Who don't want their kings
<br>
These are a few of
<br>
My favorite things.
</p>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I want tooltips in the left column to be flush with the left edges of the images, with the arrows centered above the images.

I want tooltips in the center column to be centered on the A, DIV or SPAN, with the arrow centered on the text.

I want tooltips in the right column to be flush with the right edges of the images, with the arrows centered above the images.

The positioning of the arrow is relative to its immediate container, but I need to make it relative to the grandfather rather than the father. I thought of using calc(), but I don't know how to capture the absolute container boundaries. Is there a way to do this in CSS?

Answer (score 1):

To center the tooltip and the pointer above the element, <strike>I think you'll need to use JavaScript to get the element's width and apply positioning declarations accordingly.</strike>

After posting my answer, I happened to read an article about [CSS container queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_container_queries) and wondered if it could be used for this purpose. Indeed, I was successful in implementing it without even needing to use the `@container` at-rule.

---

To center the tooltip and the pointer above the elements in the center column, calculate a negative value of half the width of the tooltip plus half the width of the containing element, which in this case is `left: calc(-10em + 50%);`.

To position the tooltip to be flush with the left or right edge, you just need the appropriate left and/or right declarations (in this case, to overwrite the existing declarations.) `left: 0;` / `left: auto;` `right: 0;`

To center the pointer above the elements in the left and right columns, declare a [containment context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/container-type) with `container-type: inline-size;` for the containing elements and then position the pointer using [container query length units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#container_query_length_units). `50cqw` is 50% of the query container's width. `left: 50cqw;` (Keep in mind that the width of the container includes margin, padding, and borders on the elements inside the container, i.e. child elements.)

I altered your CSS to help get you going in the right direction. My modifications are indicated with `/* <- */`

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang=en>
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <TITLE>favorite things</TITLE>
        <META name="KEYWORDS" CONTENT="filk">
        <style>
            p        {
                       left:20%;
                       position:relative;
                       right:-20%;
                       margin-left:2em;
                       width:60%;
                     }

            p.drop   {
                       margin-left:2em;
                     }

            p.drop::first-letter  {
                       font-size:2em;
                       margin-left:-2em;
                     }

            a.L,div.L,span.L,a.R,div.R,span.R { /* <- */
                       display:inline;
                       --width:14%;
                       width:var(--width);
                       position:absolute;
                       container-type: inline-size; /* <- */
                     }

            a.L,div.L,span.L { /* <- */
                       left:-20%;
                     }

            a.R,div.R,span.R { /* <- */
                       right:0;
                     }

            h1       {
                       text-align:center;
                       font-size:4em;
                     }

            img.V    {
                       display:block;
                       height:auto;
                       /* margin:10% 10% 10% 10%; */ /* <- */
                       /* max-width:90%; */ /* <- */
                       width:100%;
                       margin-top: 10%; /* <- */
                     }

           /* Tooltip container */
          .tooltip {
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
            border-bottom: 1px dotted black; /* If you want dots under the hoverable text */
          }

          /* Tooltip text */
          .tooltip .tooltiptext {
            visibility: hidden;
            /* width: 120px; */ /* <- */
            width: 20em; /* <- */
            background-color: #555;
            color: #fff;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 5px 0;
            border-radius: 6px;

            /* Position the tooltip text */
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 1;
            bottom: 102%;
            left: calc(-10em + 50%); /* <- */
            /* left: -25%; */ /* <- */
            /* margin-left: -40%; */ /* <- */
            /* Min-width: 20em; */ /* <- */
            /* max-width: 70em; */ /* <- */

            /* Fade in tooltip */
            opacity: 0;
            transition: opacity 0.3s;
          }

          .L .tooltiptext {
            left: 0; /* <- */
            /* left:  -25%; */ /* <- */
            text-align: left;
          }

          .R  .tooltiptext {
            left: auto; /* <- */
            right: 0%;
            text-align: left;
          }

          /* Tooltip arrow */
          .tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            top: 100%;
            left: 50%;
            margin-left: -5px;
            border-width: 5px;
            border-style: solid;
            border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
            width: 1px;
          }

          .L .tooltiptext::after {
            /* left: calc(--width * (2/3)); */ /* <- */
            left: 50cqw; /* <- */
          }

          .R .tooltiptext::after {
            /* left: 30%; */ /* <- */
            left: auto; /* <- */
            right: 50cqw; /* <- */
          }

          /* Show the tooltip text when you mouse over the tooltip container */
          .tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
            visibility: visible;
            opacity: 1;
          }

          .verse     {
            font-size: 2em;
            text-align: center;
            width:60%
          }
        </style>
</head>
<BODY LANG="en-US" DIR="LTR">
<H1>My favorite things</H1>

<p>
[Verse]
</p>
<p class="drop verse">
Gardening
<a class=tooltip href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ungoliant">
   spiders
   <span class=tooltiptext>
     Ungoliant, who took the form of a giant spider and, along with Dark Lord Melkor, destroyed the Two Trees of Valinor
   </span>
</a>
<a class=L href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Silmarillion">
<img class=V src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/d/db/Silmarillion.png/220px-Silmarillion.png"
             alt="The Silmarillion">
</a>
<br>
<a class="R tooltip" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fellowship_of_the_Ring">
  <img class=V src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/8/8e/The_Fellowship_of_the_Ring_cover.gif"
               alt="The Fellowship of the Ring">
  <span class=tooltiptext>
     Elendil&apos;s sword Narsil, called <q>The Sword that was Broken</q> after
     its damage in a battle against Sauron, and later caried by
     Aragorn (<q>Strider</q>).
  </span>
</a>
And
<a class=tooltip href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle-earth_weapons_and_armour#Narsil">
  swords that are broken
  <span class=tooltiptext>
     Elendil&apos;s sword Narsil, called <q>The Sword that was Broken</q> after
     its damage in a battle against Sauron, and later caried by
     Aragorn (<q>Strider</q>).
  </span>
</a>
<br>
Words in the
<a class=tooltip href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Speech">
  Black Speech
  <span class=tooltiptext>
    The Black Speech of Mordor is a language constructed by Sauron.
  </span>
</a>
<br>
That must not be spoken
<br>
<a class=tooltip href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denethor">
  Unfaithful stewards
  <span class=tooltiptext>
    Denethor, the 26th ruling Steward of Gondor.
  </span>
</a>
<br>
<a class="L tooltip" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Return_of_the_King">
  <img class=V src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/1/11/The_Return_of_the_King_cover.gif/220px-The_Return_of_the_King_cover.gif"
               alt="The Return of the King">
  <span class=tooltiptext>
    Denethor, the 26th ruling Steward of Gondor.
  </span>
</a>
Who don't want their kings
<br>
These are a few of
<br>
My favorite things.
</p>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: It didn't work on Firefox ESR 45.9 so I tried it on another machine and it worked fine. Thanks.

Comment: @shmuel Firefox ESR 45.9 was released six years ago on April 19, 2017. That's like saying it didn't work in Internet Explorer LOL Okay, that's a stretch, IE11 came out 3.5 years earlier. If this is an acceptable answer, I'd appreciate the green checkmark!

Comment: That's the most recent FF on that platform; they're working on an otter port. That's why I tried it on a different machine/\.

Comment: I had already upvoted..